# Can we solve fuzzy linear programming using GLPK python?

Tags: python, linear-programming, fuzzy-logic, glpk, fuzzy

I am exploring fuzzy linear programming for my current project. I am already using GLPK API using python for solving linear programming problems. I want to know if I can solve fuzzy LPP using GLPK

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.